# Looping over Jekyll collection page's tags - displaying without spaces

Tags: ruby, jekyll, liquid

I'm trying to loop over a collection, display it's pages as links and on those links have each of that page's tags be distinct class names. I have everything working except for the fact that the tags jumble together without any spaces.

Here's how I have the tags in the front matter of a page:

```
tags:
- javascript
- jquery
- requires-springshare-auth-server
- client-side
```

Here's the liquid in my html:

```
<ul class="custom-dots">
   {% for libguide in site.libguides %}
     <li class="{{libguide.tags}}">   
        <a href="{{site.baseurl}}{{ libguide.url}}">{{libguide.title}}</a>
     </li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

And here's the rendered HTML as viewed through dev tools:

```
<li class="javascriptjqueryrequires-springshare-auth-serverclient-side">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [Liquid's `join` filter](https://help.shopify.com/themes/liquid/filters/array-filters#join).

Simple example with just a single page:

```
---
title: blah
layout: default
tags:
- javascript
- jquery
- requires-springshare-auth-server
- client-side
---

<li class="{{ page.tags | join: ' ' }}">
```

The rendered HTML:

```
 <li class="javascript jquery requires-springshare-auth-server client-side">
```

Answer (score 2):

`{{ libguide.tags }}` returns a raw output for the array, but you can separate  elements with a space using the `join` filter :

`{{ libguide.tags | join: " " }}`.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing `{{libguide.tags}}` with `{{libguide | tags}}`. It will display tags separated by comma.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Didn't work. What happened was it actually displayed the collection page on my index page. It looped through the collection and displayed each page in the collection one after the other

Comment: Can you change the tags to `tags:  javascript jquery requires-springshare-auth-server client-side` (tag names in a single line separated by space)and then try.

Comment: I tried that and it's still doing the same thing. Idk if it matter but I'm using no plugins in my Jekyll since it's a site on GitHub pages

Comment: One last thing to try. Keep the tags in a single line as previous comment and run `{% for post in site.posts %} {{ post | tags }} {% endfor %}`. I think there is no need for plugins.

Comment: Turns out that one way to do it is with a join filter. Thanks for your time!